# Change "slide to unlock" text color iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

So, what's the question: I'm trying to change "slide to unlock" text color on lockscreen. I'm using Theos to hook SBAwayLockBar class and -(void)_setLabel:(id)label method. Here's my Tweak.xm:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SBAwayLockBar
-(void)_setLabel:(id)label {

label = @"text";

%orig;
}
%end
```

And this is all what I can do with "slide to unlock" text. I have tried to change `(id)label` to `(UILabel *)label`, but my iPhone went to Safe mode after respring. So, which other method I need to call, or which type must the "slide to unlock" label be to I have ability to change its color?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I wrote this code

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

static NSString *cont;

%hook SBAwayLockBar

-(void)_setLabel:(id)label {

cont = label;

NSString *giantSpace = @" ";

for(int i = 0; i <= [cont length] * 2; i++) {

    giantSpace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", giantSpace];

}

label = giantSpace;

%orig;

}

%end


%hook TPLockTextView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

NSString *string = cont;

[[UIColor whiteColor] set]; 
[string drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19]];

%orig;

}

%end
```

, but it draws a new label with the same text as in original label and colorises the new label instead of original. What am I supposed to do/add/edit now? 
Thanks!

Comment: All types you need are located in private TelephonyUI.framework. `TPBottomLockBar` is the lock bar. It's using `TPLockTextView` to draw "slide to unlock" label. As I can see it's color is hardcoded in it's `drawRect:` method. Your could try to hook `drawRect:` and write your own implementation using disassembly as a reference. I don't see an easier way to do it.

Comment: If you call `%orig;` as the last method, then it will call the original implementation, overwriting all your previous changes. Maybe you don't want to call it at all, or you only want to call it **before** doing anything else.

Comment: I suspect that you don't quite understand the meaning of `%orig`. You don't need to call it in every method you hook, whether you call it or not is completely up to you and depends on what you are trying to achieve. Sometimes you hook a method to, let's say, modify it's arguments. In that case you need to call `%orig`. Your `_setLabel:` is exactly that case. Other times you want to completely replace method's implementation with your own and you don't wanna call `%orig` as it will break things. `drawRect:` is exactly that case. Just remove `%orig` and everything will work.